# Resolving Dependency Conflicts Installing Behat and Laravel 5.3

Tags: composer-php, behat, symfony-dependency-injection

Hello I am trying to install behat/behat via composer, however I am have dependency problems. I tried the below of many:

```
composer require behat/behat:"3.*" symfony/dependency-injection:"3.*" --dev
```

However, the output of above is

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Below is my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.11",
        "phaza/laravel-postgis": "^3.0",
        "jenssegers/raven": "1.9.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "oureastudios/laravel5-braintree": "dev-master",
        "vinkla/algolia": "^2.1",
        "alexpechkarev/google-maps": "1.0.5",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "pubnub/pubnub": "3.7.*",
        "maknz/slack": "^1.7",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "wilgucki/csv": "^0.5.1",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "@dev",
        "aloha/twilio": "^2.1",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "1.0",
        "maxmind-db/reader": "~1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap": "^1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "tests/Helpers/",
            "tests/Traits/"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:models -N",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

What combination of behat and symfony/dependency-injection I should install? I tried many versions ever issued the below command 
composer info behat/behat -a but still no avail.

Comment: Does it work when you require only one of the two packages? Can you share the whole message stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically whenever you get into this dependency nightmare, you are highly recommended to make your required versions *specific* rather than with wildcards. In other words: give Composer less room for imagination.

This is what I did to make it work:

## 1. Guess which is the best fit

Laravel 5.3 was [released](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-3-is-now-released) back in September 9, 2016, going over the Behat [releases](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/releases?after=v3.2.0), the first major release before that was [3.1.0](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/tree/v3.1.0) which was released in march 28th, 2016. So that's the first version I put in Composer *directly* (ie. without any wildcards and such) like so:

```
"behat/behat": "3.1.0",
```

## 2. Run Stuff With No Strings Attached

After that, I just ran the following:

- `composer dump-autoload`: clean up caches
- `rm -rf vendor` and `rm composer.lock`: just to make life easier
- `composer install --no-scripts`: just to make sure that `php artisan` stuff don't run.
- profit

> ```
> composer show | grep behat
> behat/behat                           v3.1.0               Scenario-oriented BDD framework for PHP 5.3
> behat/gherkin                         v4.5.1               Gherkin DSL parser for PHP 5.3
> behat/transliterator                  v1.2.0               String transliterator
> ```